# custom paypal buttons in Joomla 3.0

Tags: php, html, paypal, joomla3.0

when using a custom image for the paypal 'buy now' button under Joomla can I use the button code creator and what is the correct url format to use ? The code creator site just gives the generic http:// prefix but I want to use a custom graphic/button from my images folder under Joomla 3.0. can I do this ? and if so what is the format of the URL I need to enter e.g. http:\ww.mysite.co.uk\images\buutons\mybutton ?

Answer (score 0):

Take your standard PayPal provided code and look for some portion of the code that looks like this:`<input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" /> <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" />`
You should replace the src= URL with your custom button/image url so that the code would now be:`<input type="image" name="submit" src="http://www.your-site.com/button.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" /> <img src="http://www.your-site.com/button.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" />` Given that button.gif is your image file location.
I hope that helps.  Note that you don't use https.